# findGCD function never completes

Tags: python

I was exercising to improve my coding but when I try to use this code and run, terminal just freezes and not giving any error at all, I cant do anything either until I press `ctrl+c`. Cause of its not giving error I don't know what did I wrong.

```py
# 31. Write a Python program to compute the greatest common divisor (GCD) of two positive integers.

def findGCD(num,num1):
    numDivided = 0
    num1Divided = 0
    while True:
        num/2
        numDivided+=1
        num1/2
        num1Divided+=1
        if num and num1 == 1 or 0:
            break
    gcd = numDivided*num1Divided
    print(gcd)

findGCD(101,102)
```

Comment: `if num and num1 == 1 or 0:` doesn't do what you think it does

Comment: A line like `num/2` does nothing, the result of the division isn't stored.

Comment: `if (num == 1 or num == 0) and (num1 == 1 or num == 0)` is the way to write that logic. Note that everything between the `and` and `or` are full conditions that return True/False. You can also make this more succinct with something like: `if num in (1,0) and num1 in (1,0):`

Comment: "Terminal freezes" should only be used as a description if you've proved that it's the _terminal program itself_ doing something wrong (for example, you can get there if there's an XOFF character being sent with no XON later). If your function doesn't finish, that's not the terminal's fault as long as the terminal continues to print content if/when it's sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous mistakes including the incorrect `if` statement referred to above. `num/2` will calculate something but this will be a float value if num is odd; then you do nothing with the result; same for num1/2. To find GCD you have to use integer arithmetic. Incidently 101 and 102 have only the GCD of 1 so maybe not the best example. The code below works. I suggest you paint it into https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit to step through the code and see how it works.

```
def findGCD(num, num1):
    if num > num1:
        hold = num1
    else:
        hold = num
    for i in range(1, hold + 1):
        if ((num % i == 0) and (num1 % i ==0)):
            gcd = i
    return gcd
```